# Automatic split of character matrix according to a column values into variable number of new dataframes

Tags: r

I would like to split a character matrix I have according to one of the column values.
so if for example I have 3 columns and "n" rows, and I want to use column number 2 as reference. The script should look in the second column and group all rows that contain the same value into a dataframe.

So, say I have "A", "B", "C", "D" and "E" values in column 2 through "n" rows. I want to get (in this case) 5 new dataframes containing all rows of data conditioned to the second column values. So all rows that contain "A" in the second column of the matrix go to one dataframe and so on.

My data is much bigger, containing around 400 different character values in the column I want to use as reference (column 2 in the above example) to split so this process needs to be automatic, I mean, it has to automatically detect how many new dataframes should be created according to the number of different values in "column 2".

Here is a shorter example of what i need:

```
structure(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low", "A", "D", "A", "C", "8", 
"3", "9", "9", "1", "1", "1", "2"), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("b", "x", "y", "z")))
```

Here I would need to have 3 new dataframes if I use (again) column 2 ("x") as reference. One dataframe containing  rows 1 and 3, another dataframe containing row 2 and a final one containing row 4, as there are 3 different values in that column: "A", "D" and "C".

The new dataframes should be named automatically as the value they are being grouped with. So the first dataframe should be named "A", the second "D" and so on. Is it possible to make all this process automatic with my bigger data?

I hope I was clear enough, and sorry if this was already answered before but i couldnt find a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you're looking for the `split` function.

```
x <- structure(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low", 
                 "A", "D", "A", "C", 
                 "8", "3", "9", "9", 
                 "1", "1", "1", "2"), 
               .Dim = c(4L, 4L), 
               .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("b", "x", "y", "z")))
split(data.frame(x), x[, 2])
# $A
#    b x y z
# 1 Hi A 8 1
# 3 Hi A 9 1
# 
# $C
#     b x y z
# 4 Low C 9 2
# 
# $D
#     b x y z
# 2 Med D 3 1
```

The resulting `data.frame`s are all in a single `list`, but you can do things with `assign` if you want to actually split them into individual `data.frame`s in your workspace.

Comment: Thank you, it splits the data perfectly. Now, I still need to create the "n" number of dataframes automatically from the list. I tried looking at the assign function as you mentioned but havent been able to make an automatic creation of the dataframes since the number of dataframes to be created will be changing as the data changes. Any further help on this would be very appreciated :)

Comment: @RabidHealer, assuming you stored the output of `split` as an object named "y", use `list2env(y, envir=.GlobalEnv)`.