# Automatic split of cell array according to a column values into variable number of new cell arrays

Tags: matlab, split

Some time ago I asked this question: [Automatic split of character matrix according to a column values into variable number of new dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206550/automatic-split-of-character-matrix-according-to-a-column-values-into-variable-n)

For that question the function `split` was the perfect answer, now, I am triying to do the same in Matlab and cannot find any function that does the same.

So, its simple, my question is: Is there any function that does the same as the R `split` function in Matlab? and if not, how could I do exactly what was asked in the linked question in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need is the new table class R2013b:

```
>> x = {'Hi', 'Med', 'Hi', 'Low'; 'A', 'D', 'A', 'C'; '8', '3', '9', '9'; '1', '1', '1', '2'}';
>> t = cell2table(x)

t = 

     x1      x2     x3     x4 
    _____    ___    ___    ___

    'Hi'     'A'    '8'    '1'
    'Med'    'D'    '3'    '1'
    'Hi'     'A'    '9'    '1'
    'Low'    'C'    '9'    '2'

>> slice = t(strcmp(t.x2,'A'),:)

slice = 

     x1     x2     x3     x4 
    ____    ___    ___    ___

    'Hi'    'A'    '8'    '1'
    'Hi'    'A'    '9'    '1'

>>
```

For more information, take a look at the table class [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html)

If you'd like to do this for all unique values of the table you can leverage cellfun:

```
>> slices = cellfun(@(value) t(strcmp(t.x2,value),:), unique(t.x2),'UniformOutput',false)

slices = 

    [2x4 table]
    [1x4 table]
    [1x4 table]

>> slices{:}

ans = 

     x1     x2     x3     x4 
    ____    ___    ___    ___

    'Hi'    'A'    '8'    '1'
    'Hi'    'A'    '9'    '1'


ans = 

     x1      x2     x3     x4 
    _____    ___    ___    ___

    'Low'    'C'    '9'    '2'


ans = 

     x1      x2     x3     x4 
    _____    ___    ___    ___

    'Med'    'D'    '3'    '1'

>>
```

In this case you are passing every unique element of t.x2 into this function. Uniform output must be false so that cellfun does not try to concatenate the tables together but rather puts each slice of the table into its own cell.

Comment: This partially works but the problem is when you use `strcmp` function you must tell the function to look for "A" for example and this creates only one table with all rows that have "A" in column 2... And in my case I need to do this automatically, because in this case for example I have "A", "D" and "C" but this will be variable and I need one table containing each different value in column 2, in this case 3 tables... But all of this should be done automatically: detect how many unique values are in column 2 and then create a new table with all data that shares each unique value.

Comment: Then you can use cellfun to do this over all unique values of the row in question. I've updated my answer reflecting this

Answer (score 1):

The `unique` and `strcmp` functions works on cell arrays. What about something like

```
x = {'Hi', 'Med', 'Hi', 'Low'; 'A', 'D', 'A', 'C'; '8', '3', '9', '9'; '1', '1', '1', '2'}';

for ii = unique(x(:, 3))'
    x(find(strcmp(x(:, 3), ii)), :)
end
```

While it may seems silly, the index array for the for loop must be a row so in `unique(x(:, 3))'` the transpose operator is critical. If done correctly `ii` is a scalar. Otherwise you will get the error

> Error using strcmp Inputs must be the same size or either one can be
>   a scalar

Comment: @RabidHealer did you copy my example exactly? While it may seems silly, the index array for the for loop must be a row so in `unique(x(:, 3))'` the transpose operator is critical. If done correctly `ii` is a scalar.

Comment: My mistake, I did not copy it but tried to write it by myself while I was understanding what each part did. It now works but there is still a problem. I need in each loop to create a variable with the gruped data that corresponds to "ii". I am making tests with `genvarname` but still unsuccessful.

Comment: @RabidHealer you need to edit your question to include more information. As it stands there is no way to know what you want the output to be. Why not create a counter `jj` and save the output into a cell array `y{jj} = x(find(strcmp...`

Comment: @RabidHealer please consider deleting your comment which says the code doesn't work.

Comment: In the linked queastion I explain what output I want. Here is a summary: I need an "n" number of cell arrays(or structs or tables) that contains in each one the grouped rows that share the same value in a defined column. So, basically I need to split a big cell array into a variable number of smaller ones according to a condition (which in this case is the shared value in a column), so, as said in the linked question, for that example i would need 3 new cell arrays since the column I am using as a reference for the condition has 3 different unique values ("A","D" and "C")